# Why is it that Harry Potter is the only one who should defeat Voldemort?

Tags: harry-potter

In the Harry Potter universe, I understand there is this prophecy by Sybill Trelawney:

> The one with the power to vanquish the Dark Lord approaches... born to those who have thrice defied him, born as the seventh month dies... and the Dark Lord will mark him as his equal, but he will have power the Dark Lord knows not... and either must die at the hand of the other for neither can live while the other survives... the one with the power to vanquish the Dark Lord will be born as the seventh month dies...
>   Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix, *The Department of Mysteries.*

My question is why Harry or Neville?

Albus Dumbledore is the most powerful wizard in the Harry Potter universe, having defeated Grindelwald in 1945 and gained control of the Elder Wand. I understand very well, he never became the 'Master of Death', the Master of Deathly Hallows, also he accepted his death and death could not conquer him and Dumbledore calls him the 'true Master of Death' in Deathly Hallows. Is this a possible reason why Harry is the one who can defeat Voldemort?

I mean: Dumbledore defeated Grindelwald in an epic duel without any Deathly Hallow? He could have destroyed all the horcruxes, much before Harry Potter was born and defeated Voldemort. He wouldn't have known about it, true..and maybe after Harry was born he'd have to kill Harry because he unwittingly was a horcrux, but one death is nothing compared to what Voldemort would have done in power, right?

I feel in a duel with Voldemort and Dumbledore, Dumbledore would eventually win because Voldemort always feared him and Dumbledore knows how to take him down.

I mean I understand in Lord of the Rings, none of the 'Wise' could destroy the One Ring because by even accepting the ring they could become a next Dark Lord, and hence it had to be Frodo, Sam, and Gollum because they had qualities different from Men, Elves, Wizard, Dwarves etc.

Why is Harry so important?

Comment: V had chosen him for the job. Also             http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/56142/why-didnt-dumbledore-just-hunt-voldemort-down

Comment: Thanks for that..sorry I didn't see that question before.

Comment: If the linked question answers your question you should probably mark yours as a duplicate. That way those who will come after will find the information they need easier. You can mark your question as a duplicate by using the **flag** button beneath it.

Comment: Are you asking about *before* Voldemort was "killed" or after? Or both?

Comment: Dumbledore seems to have a passion for using other people, especially children, as cannon fodder in his magical chess game with Voldemort

Comment: Note that when Dumbledore *did* start hunting down Horcruxes, he was fatally injured by the very first one he found, and was unable to obtain the second one (which turned out to be a fake anyway) without Harry's help.  This doesn't exactly lend me confidence in the "Dumbledore could have done it himself" theory. :-)

Comment: Also, strongly related: [Why Was It 'Essential' That Voldemort Kill Harry Potter?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/15938/21267)